# Show that there is a simultaneously tangent line to both the curves $y = e^x$ and $y = \ln x$

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

I found the derivatives of both of the curves but I'm having trouble on how to move on from here:

$y = e^x\implies y' = e^x$

$y = \ln x\implies y' = \frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 4):

Let the tangent have the equation $y=ax+b$.

The condition of tangency to the exponential at $x_e$ is written

$$ax_e+b=e^{x_e},a=e^{x_e}$$

and that to the logarithm at $x_l$ is

$$ax_l+b=\log x_l,a=\frac1{x_l}.$$

We eliminate $x_e,x_l$,

$$a\log a+b=a$$

$$1+b=-\log a$$

then $b$, and we get

$$a\log a-a-\log a-1=0.$$

As the LHS is continuous, negative at $a=e$ and positive at $a=e^2$, there is certainly a solution, hence a common tangent.

---

As mentioned by @user3733558, there is another solution. By symmetry, it must correspond to the substitution $a\leftrightarrow\dfrac1a$. Indeed we verify

$$-\frac{\log a}a-\frac1a+\log a-1=\frac{a\log a-a-\log a-1}a=0.$$

Comment: Maybe you meant $a=e^2$ in that last sentence? Remark: LHS is also positive for $a=e^{-2}$, so there are more than one common tangent.

Comment: @user3733558: right, fixed. Existence of a single solution is enough, and the second was expected, by symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

Given  \begin{align} y = e^x\implies y' = e^x$, $y = \ln x\implies y' = \frac{1}{x}\end{align}

Tangent line to $y = e^x$ at x=a
\begin{align} y=e^ax+e^a(1-a)\end{align}

Tangent line to $y=lnx$ at x=b\begin{align} y=\frac{1}{b}x+\ln b-1\end{align}

When the two lines become one line:

\begin{align} e^a=\frac{1}{b}, e^a(1-a)=\ln b-1\end{align}

Solve the above equations about a and b, \begin{align}b \approx 0.124, a\approx ln(\frac{1}{0.214}) \\b\approx 4.681, a\approx ln( \frac{1}{4.681}) \end{align}

The common tangent lines  \begin{align}  y= \frac{1}{0.214}x+\ln(0.214)-1 \\y= \frac{1}{4.681}x+\ln(4.681)-1  \end{align}

Comment: There's a second common tangent. Your system has two real solutions; the other one with $b\approx 4.6805.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: mirror the plot around the first bissector.

Comment: Thanks, updated:-)

Answer (score 1):

The tangent to $y=\ln x$ at $(1,0)$ does not intersect the curve $y=e^x$.

On the other hand, the tangent to $y = \ln x$ at $(10,\ln 10)$ is *below* $e^x$ at $(10, \ln 10)$ but above $e^x$ at $(0,\ln(10)-1)$, since $\ln(10)-1 \approx 1.303$. So that tangent does intersect $e^x$ at least once.

Thus, if you *slide* a tangent smoothly along $y=\ln x$ such that its point of tangency moves from $(1,0)$ to $(10,\ln(10))$, at some point the number of intersections between the tangent and $e^x$ will change from "none" to "some".

Hopefully you can argue that *in that particular* position, the tangent to $y=\ln x$ is necessarily also a tangent to $y=e^x$. (Precisely how to conduct that argument depends on the level of rigor expected of you in the context you're given the exercise; you might be able to get away with greater or smaller amounts of handwaving).

Note that the task you quote doesn't ask you to *find* the common tangent, just to prove that a common tangent *exists* somewhere.